# Insert users first name from SharePoint Security Group

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, email

I created a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010.  When an item is added to a library an email gets sent to all recipients.

The recipients are being pulled from a custom SharePoint group that I created.

I can get the email to send out to all the users email who are in the security group but in the body of the email I'm trying to insert the users first and last name and that's where I come across an error.

Workflow failed to get user profile for user:**Daily Report Group**

Daily Report Group is the custom group that I created and here's the lookup I tried to do

**Field Data to retrieve**

**Data Source** Source: User Profile

**Field from Source** Name

**Find the list item**

**Field Data To Retrieve** Account Name

**Value**: Daily Report Group

What am I doing wrong? Would it be easier to pull all the recipients info from a list instead?

Comment: Are you looping to send email to individual users? Use DataSource=UserList. FieldFromSource=Name. Field=Email. Value=`Email You Have For That User`

Comment: No but I probably need too.  If I sent

Comment: So I should pull the emails and user info from a list instead of a sharepoint group?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65e5dfc7-626b-47f0-bf56-b58a08219db7/send-email-to-sharepoint-group-using-spd-workflows-not-working?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: I can send the emails out to everyone in the SharePoint group but pulling the first name, of the users, in the SharePoint group, and inserting it in the body of the email is what I'm having trouble with

Comment: In that case you are not sending a static content and hence you need to iterate through and sent it individually

Comment: So how do i go about doing that?  SharePoint Designer doesn't do loops